# Asp.net Application State Expiration Issue

Tags: asp.net, application-state

I am having an issue with the data in the Application object expiring within 1 minute. I need the data in this object to persist at least 15 - 20 minutes after the last user of the web application leaves. This used to work fine, but I have had this problem ever since my system admin moved from physical hardware to a VM. There must be some configuration that we are missing that is causing this problem.

The setup is IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2. My web application is using the the defaultAppPool with ASP 4.0 classic. I checked the settings at it is using 1740 minutes for recycling, so I am lost as to what else could cause this problem.

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Comment: Is your website based on compiled files(.dlls) or you deploy the source code instead and let ASP.NET to compile it for you?

Comment: The ASPX pages are published to the website, but only the ASPX and the dlls.